# Unrecognized accessed paths - is my server being attacked?

Tags: networking, server, apache2, security, nodejs

My website seems to be having some malicious visitors and crashing my site often. I am now tracking what they are doing on my site. In my log, I found out they are accessing the following paths through my site:

```
/cgi-bin/luci
/cgi-bin/luci/admin
/Display/chan/IB61I7MYA
/Visu/ens/events
/v2sA
/fw6I
/includ
/viwwwsogou
/is-bin
/AVuP
/PPsJ
/zMLUH93A
... and more
```

I don't have these paths and pages set or created on my site. Why would they want to access these paths through my site? What are they trying to do? Is my server being attacked? How can I be sure and stop that?

My site is a Node.js app by the way. My live server is running Ubuntu:

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS
Release:        22.04
Codename:       jammy
```

I also have Apache running on my server, alongside Node.js.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5):

> NOTE: This is said with my IT Security Professional hat on, which comes with over 10 years of analyzing network traffic and attack/scanner patterns.

What you are seeing is **typical service scanner traffic** - it's not a direct attack on you, but part of a larger trend of behavior of bad guys and malware attempting to find vulnerable vectors to infect/hijack your services.

Everything connected to the Internet gets scanned for activity, services that're running, etc.  Web servers and services in particular are a target, as numerous URLs exist that are used to run certain software or services and then can be potentially vulnerable to attack and exploit vectors.

**If your Internet site is public, this is Expected Observed Traffic for a typical system setup.**  If you do not yet have a firewall enabled on system to block traffic to *other* ports, you should set one up.

If your web service is self written, you may want to use a web application scanner [such as this one](https://pentest-tools.com/website-vulnerability-scanning/website-scanner) (I am not affiliated with this site and have not personally audited it), or by running a Nessus scanner or other open source scanner kit against your software's web URL to see if it's vulnerable to any of the common attack paths and exploit vectors.

Make sure your NodeJS service is audited regularly though if it's public.  Not keeping your software secure *can* lead to your systems being breached.

Comment: I couldn't agree more ... @Run Those seem not to be specifically targeted to you nor they seem to be well thought but rather arbitrary automated scans as it looks or armature's work ... `/cgi-bin/luci/admin` for example is the the web management page for OpenWrt router firmware (they don't seem to even do pre-checks on machine fingerprint) and `/includ` seems like looking for a script that might be used to include files from higher system hierarchy so they can try exploiting it to access your files outside the web root and so on.

Comment: @Thomas, thanks. I got a list of risk reports from https://pentest-tools.com/website-vulnerability-scanning/website-scanner. For example, "Some mod_proxy configurations on Apache HTTP Server versions 2.4.0 through 2.4.55 allow a HTTP Request Smuggling attack." The recommendation from the report, "We recommend you to upgrade the affected software to the latest version in order to eliminate the risk of these vulnerabilities." It seems that it is Apache might be at risk. I have my Ubuntu updated regularly. So the recommendation goes nowhere.

Comment: @Run When processing *those* types of results you have to check the specific CVEs and vulnerabilities those responses/warnings state and see if they are already patched in your system by the Ubuntu distribution.  Typically the severe ones are, but the only way to check is to audit those output results, and check the CVEs against the CVE tracker (https://ubuntu.com/security/cves) and then see if the CVE is 'patched' or not and then check your package version for Apache2 against the 'fixed' version on the tracker for your given Ubuntu release.